# Inject Entity Framework Core Context into repository with ServiceStack when unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core, servicestack

I have a repository class

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public PersonRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<PersonDto> Fetch() ......
}
```

I then have a ServiceStack PersonsService

```
public class PersonsServices : Service
{
    private IPersonsRepository _personRepo;

    public PersonsServices(IPersonsRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepo = personRepository;
    }

    public object Any(GetPersons request)
    {
        return new GetPersonssResponse
        {
            Results = _personsRepo.Fetch()
        };
    }
}
```

My code works fine in the ServiceStack app as the DataContext is injected in by .Net Core as configured in the AddDbContext method in Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x
    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

How do I do this in a unit test in conjunction with ServiceStack and using .Net Core Entity Framework?

I need something equivalent to the AddDbContext here.  Ultimately my goal is to create unit tests that use an in-memory or SQLite context but keep the same repository code.

EDIT: Here is what my unit test looks like so far.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class PersonTest
    {
        private ServiceStackHost appHost;

        [SetUp]
        public void TestFixtureSetUp()
        {
            appHost = new BasicAppHost().Init();
            var container = appHost.Container;

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                   .Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlite(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

//HOW TO GET SERVICESTACK / FUNQ TO RESOLVE THE DataContext IN REPOSITORY???

```
            **container.Register<IDataContext>(i => new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options)).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);**
            container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<PersonRepository, IPersonRepository>();

        }

        [Test]
        public async Task GetPersons()
        {
            var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<PersonsServices>();

            var response = await service.Any(new GetPersons { });
            var results = (GetPersonsResponse)response;

            Assert.That(1 == 1);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TestFixtureTearDown()
        {
            appHost.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This documentation on [Unit Testing .NET Core EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) shows you how can create an In Memory DataContext which you can then inject into your Services constructor:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
    .Options;

// Run the test against one instance of the context
using (var context = new BloggingContext(options))
{
    var service = new BlogService(context);
}
```

So you could pass in the DataContext and Repository in your Service:

```
using (var service = new PersonsServices(new PersonRepository(new DataContext(...))))
{
    var response = service.Any(new GetPersons { });
}
```

Or register the EF DataContext in Funq's IOC:

```
container.Register<DataContext>(i => new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options));
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<PersonRepository, IPersonRepository>();

//...
using (var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<PersonsServices>())
{
}
```

#### Tips

- What you register needs to be the exact type that's being resolved, e.g. since `PersonRepository` accepts a `DataContext` you must register a `DataContext` not `IDataContext`.
- Don't use Request Scope outside of a HTTP Request, you can use either transient or singleton since there's only a single thread in a unit test.
- If you're going to call your Services methods directly you may as well specify the Type on your Service method.

E.g:

```
public GetPersonsResponse Any(GetPersons request) => 
    new GetPersonsResponse {
        Results = _personsRepo.Fetch()
    };
```

Which will avoid having to cast to the response in your Unit test (which is wrong in the example provided as it's trying to await a synchronous method returning an object). Specifying the Response Type or `object` has no effect in ServiceStack

If you're using an In Memory Database consider creating [Integration Tests](https://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing) instead where you can use `AppSelfHostBase` which for [.NET Core is in the ServiceStack.Kestrel](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#appselfhostbase-source-compatible-self-host) package. You can override `ConfigureServices()` to register dependencies in .NET Core's IOC.

Comment: Thanks.  If I wasn't using ServiceStack for sure this would be the answer, but just need to figure out how to register and resolve with ServiceStack, or if I can use the ServicesCollection that exists in StartUp.cs here in a unit test.

Comment: @richardb I've updated my answer, you can pass the Repository directly into the Service class (i.e. it doesn't need to be resolved from the IOC).  If your Service relies on `Request` object then you should really be creating an Integration test to test it properly although you can use `BasicRequest` to mock it with an Empty request in a Unit test.

Comment: container.Register<DataContext>(i => new DataContext(optionsBuilder.Options));  That was what I needed - perfect thanks.  Cheers for the other tips too.